# Scraping the full content from a lazy-loading webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium, xpath

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium which is able to scrape 1000 links from a webpage in which lazy-loading method is applied for that reason it displays it's content 20 at a time and full content can only be seen when it is made to scroll downmost. However, my script can scroll the webpage to the end. After collecting the 1000 links from main page, it then gets to each individual link to scrape the Name of CEO and Web address of that organization. It is working great now. I tried to make the whole thing accordingly. Here is the full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def get_links(driver):

    driver.get('http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/')

    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(3)

        links = [posts.get_attribute("href") for posts in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' small-12 ')]//a")]
        if (len(links) == 1000):
                break

    for link in links:
        process_links(driver, link)

def process_links(driver, sub_links):

    driver.get(sub_links)

    for items in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"company-info-card-table")]'):
        Name = items.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"small-7")]/p[@class="remove-bottom-margin"]')
        Web = items.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"small-9")]/a')

        print(Name.text, Web.get_attribute("href"))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        get_links(driver)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Code Flow:

- you are redefining `links` on every iterations of the `while` loop - you basically need to do it once
- as a `while` loop exit condition, we can use the fact that there are line numbers in the company list grid - we can simply wait for the number `1000` to show up while scrolling
- I would also create a class to have the `driver` and `WebDriverWait` instance shared across the class instance methods
- instead of a hardcoded 3 second delay, use an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) with a condition of the last line number to change - this would be much faster and reliable overall

#### Code Style:

- `posts` variable name does not actually correspond to what it is - name it `company_link` instead
- `Name` and `Web` violate [PEP8 Python naming guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
- `process_links` should be `process_link` - since you are processing a single link at a time. And, actually, we can name it `get_company_data` and let it return the data instead of printing it

#### Locating Elements:

- don't use XPaths to locate elements - they are generally the slowest and the least readable
- for the company links, I'd better use a more readable and concise `ul.company-list > li > a` CSS selector
- in the `process_links` method you don't actually need a loop since there is a single company being processed. And, I think, you can generalize and return a dictionary generated from a company web page data dynamically - data labels to data values

Here is the modified working code:

```
from pprint import pprint

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class Fortune500Scraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    def get_last_line_number(self):
        """Get the line number of last company loaded into the list of companies."""
        return int(self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.company-list > li:last-child > a > span:first-child").text)

    def get_links(self, max_company_count=1000):
        """Extracts and returns company links (maximum number of company links for return is provided)."""
        self.driver.get('http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/')
        self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.company-list")))

        last_line_number = 0
        while last_line_number < max_company_count:
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

            self.wait.until(lambda driver: self.get_last_line_number() != last_line_number)
            last_line_number = self.get_last_line_number()

        return [company_link.get_attribute("href")
                for company_link in self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.company-list > li > a")]

    def get_company_data(self, company_link):
        """Extracts and prints out company specific information."""
        self.driver.get(company_link)

        return {
            row.find_element_by_css_selector(".company-info-card-label").text: row.find_element_by_css_selector(".company-info-card-data").text
            for row in self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.company-info-card-table > .columns > .row')
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = Fortune500Scraper()

    company_links = scraper.get_links(max_company_count=100)
    for company_link in company_links:
        company_data = scraper.get_company_data(company_link)
        pprint(company_data)
        print("------")
```

Prints:

```
{'CEO': 'C. Douglas McMillon',
 'CEO Title': 'President, Chief Executive Officer & Director',
 'Employees': '2,300,000',
 'HQ Location': 'Bentonville, AR',
 'Industry': 'General Merchandisers',
 'Sector': 'Retailing',
 'Website': 'www.walmart.com',
 'Years on Fortune 500 List': '23'}
------
{'CEO': 'Warren E. Buffett',
 'CEO Title': 'Chairman & Chief Executive Officer',
 'Employees': '367,700',
 'HQ Location': 'Omaha, NE',
 'Industry': 'Insurance: Property and Casualty (Stock)',
 'Sector': 'Financials',
 'Website': 'www.berkshirehathaway.com',
 'Years on Fortune 500 List': '23'}
------
...
```